# Prevent angular ui-view from attaching ng-leave

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an angular ui-view and a menu overlay in my index.html. When the ui-view is visible the menu is hidden and when the overlay is fullscreen ,the ui-view needs to be there(visible under the transparent overlay) with the transparent overlay on top.

However,when the overlay is fullscreen, the ui-view attaches ng-leave class and the contents of the view are removed.

How can i preserve the ui-view contents and prevent ng-leave when the overlay is fullscreen.

Comment: did you try removing the class manually using Jquery?

Comment: no..did not try that. I am not sure how to do that either.

Comment: UI router provides state change events given in this link:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events

Implement logic of removing the ng-leave class in this event handler

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of ui-view attaching the ng-leave class?

Comment: actually..the ui-view gets reloaded each time which makes the contents disappear from it.

Comment: can you post your code?